# Create/Enable App Engine Application for existing project?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

How do you create/enable a Google App Engine Application in an existing Google APIs Console Project? For instance, I have an existing Project because I use Android Maps in my App. However, I'd like to add to that a simple web app (maybe a website) but I don't know how to get about this. All I know is how  to create a new google app engine app which automatically creates a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for some strange reason, you can create a GAE project and then generate a new, connected, API console project - but not the other way around.  Nor can you arbitrarily connect console projects and GAE projects.

On the other hand, you don't have to.  As with the old style API projects (for which their was no concept of connecting an API and GAE project), you can use a GAE project with an API console project that are not formally connected.  And your API project can be used with multiple client projects, e.g. your Android and your web app.  See 'API's and auth', 'registered apps', and then register a new app.

Actually, I'm not completely certain whether you are asking about formally connecting GAE to API projects, or just about having multiple gae project informally used a single API project, but hopefully that helps either way.

Comment: Yeah, I think it doesn't go both ways. My goal is to just use a single project (for the website, API keys, and maybe some backend support). I ended up deleting my old project, creating a new GAE app, then getting the API keys from there. You're correct in saying that I didn't have to (I could have used multiple projects), but I hate to have to use more than one.